# Reading same cache from different microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, azure-redis-cache

Am using spring-data-redis(2.1.5.RELEASE) and jedis(2.10.2) client to connect to my azure redis instance from different services running as spring-boot application.

Two services has the same caching methods and pointed to the same cache by implementing the following configuration. The problem am facing is when one service trying to read a cached value created by another service, de-seralization exception occurs.

**Exception:**

> org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

**Note:** Am using redis only to cache the data read from my database.

### Redis Cache Configuration of microservice 1

```
public RedisCacheWriter redisCacheWriter(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return RedisCacheWriter.nonLockingRedisCacheWriter(connectionFactory);
}

@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
    Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> cacheNamesConfigurationMap = new HashMap<>();
    cacheNamesConfigurationMap.put("employers", RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(90000)));
    cacheNamesConfigurationMap.put("employees", RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(90000)));

    RedisCacheManager manager = new RedisCacheManager(redisCacheWriter(), RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig(), cacheNamesConfigurationMap);
    manager.setTransactionAware(true);
    manager.afterPropertiesSet();

    return manager;
}
```

### Redis Cache Configuration of microservice 2

```
public RedisCacheWriter redisCacheWriter(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return RedisCacheWriter.nonLockingRedisCacheWriter(connectionFactory);
}

@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
    Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> cacheNamesConfigurationMap = new HashMap<>();
    cacheNamesConfigurationMap.put("employees", RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(90000)));

    RedisCacheManager manager = new RedisCacheManager(redisCacheWriter(), RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig(), cacheNamesConfigurationMap);
    manager.setTransactionAware(true);
    manager.afterPropertiesSet();

    return manager;
}
```

### Caching methods in both services

`@Cacheable(value = "employees", key = "#employeesId")
public Employee getEmployee(String employeesId) {
    //methods
}`

### Employee class in both services

`public class Employee implements Serializable {
private String id;
private String name;
}`

Comment: can you post the exact exception that you're getting?

Comment: @MuhammadInshal I have added the exception am facing.

Comment: @Venkat are these two separate applications or is it the same application deployed twice?

Comment: @Jerome these two are separate applications and if deploy the same application twice, service is able to read read the cached data(which is created by that service)

Comment: Found the issue. Had Employee.java in different packages

Comment: @Venkat did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Roul As, mentioned. Employee classes are serialized with the package name. So in different microservices, Employee class should added under the same package path. Eg. : src/java/com/company/domain/Employee

Answer (score 2):

Either make sure the returned (de(serialized)) object is in exact same package or prevent registering the class in the data. This happens because the class name with full package qualified name are set into the data (JSON in my case). Here are the configuration I used to

- Do not get restricted using same class name of a dto !
- Use typed de-(serialization) and not generic types for converting from/to JSON
- Remove the class mark put in the data

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer() {
        return builder -> {
            Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> configurationMap = new HashMap<>();
            configurationMap.put("whatever-cache-name",
                    RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                            .entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(3600))
                            .serializeValuesWith(
                                    SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Employee.class))
                            )
            );
            builder.withInitialCacheConfigurations(configurationMap);
        };
    }

}
```

To only

- Remove the class mark put in the data

Just use instead a different serializer

```java
@AutoWired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Bean
    RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer() {
        return builder -> {
            Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> configurationMap = new HashMap<>();
            configurationMap.put("whatever-cache-name",
                    RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                            .entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(3600))
                            .serializeValuesWith(
                                    SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper))
                            )
            );
            builder.withInitialCacheConfigurations(configurationMap);
        };
    }
```

Note that by default the `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` creates new `ObjectMapper` if you don't provide one in the constructor and the default implementation will add the full qualified class name in the data and that's why I used the one provided by Spring as it was properly configured enough in that case.

Comment: Extremely helpful and saved me hours of investigating. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make sure the Employee classes are identical and then add a serialVersionUID field to the classes. Clear the Redis cache and try again.

This is from the Javadocs in the java.io.Serializable interface:

> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then
>     the serialization runtime will calculate a default serialVersionUID value
>     for that class based on various aspects of the class, as described in the
>     Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification.  However, it is *strongly
>     recommended* that all serializable classes explicitly declare
>     serialVersionUID values, since the default serialVersionUID computation is
>     highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler
>     implementations, and can thus result in unexpected
>     `InvalidClassException`s during deserialization.  Therefore, to
>     guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID value across different java compiler
>     implementations, a serializable class must declare an explicit
>     serialVersionUID value.  It is also strongly advised that explicit
>     serialVersionUID declarations use the `private` modifier where
>     possible, since such declarations apply only to the immediately declaring
>     class--serialVersionUID fields are not useful as inherited members.

Comment: I have added the serialVersionUID like you suggested, still am facing the same `ClassNotFoundException`